# Using TkCon for REPL type Tcl Console App

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there a way to make my simple tcl console (REPL type) app like below:

```
puts "Enter your name"
set name [gets stdin]
puts "You entered: $name --- Enter another name"
set name2 [gets stdin]
puts "You entered: $name2"
```

can be made to use tkcon, actually I don't want to use cmd in Windows.

I tried below code using tkcon:

```
package require tkcon 
tkcon show

puts "Enter your name"
set name [gets stdin]
puts "You entered: $name ---  Enter another name"
set name2 [gets stdin]
puts "You entered: $name2"
```

It worked. but after executing my tcl script it goes into interactive mode. It should behave like a normal console app. And it shouldnot show "wize-win-3.2 % 2" prompt.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing you could do would be to put an explicit `exit` at the end of your script, probably with some sort of delay. You'll want to do the delay in the event loop, which means putting the `exit` in a callback.

```
after 5000 exit
vwait for-termination;    # Arbitrary variable name ;-)
```

However, if you're really going for requiring a GUI to be there in the first place, making a simple Tk application isn't particularly hard.

Comment: can you point me to a example? If you run the second code above you will definitely find the point what I am asking. Putting exit explicitly will not work, the above code just ran and showed "wize-win 3.2 % 2" prompt. How to suppress this prompt.